# Using IF statements in DB2 Store procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

How would I use IF and ELSE statements to define how much of the stored procedure to run based on 'depth INTEGER'? (EG, if the user used 1 for the depth perimeter, only the first part would be processed)

```
--#SET TERMINATOR /

CREATE PROCEDURE STOREP2(IN str_in VARCHAR(1), IN depth INTEGER )
                    LANGUAGE SQL MODIFIES SQL DATA
                    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1


CRSUBJ: BEGIN

DECLARE C1 CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR 

SELECT T1.COLUMN1, T1.COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1 AS T1 WHERE T1.COLUMN1=str_in

UNION

SELECT T2.COLUMN1, T2.COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1 AS T1, TABLE1 AS T2 WHERE T1.COLUMN1=str_in AND T2.COLUMN1=T1.COLUMN2

UNION 

SELECT T3.COLUMN1, T3.COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1 AS T1, TABLE1 AS T2, TABLE1 AS T3 WHERE T1.COLUMN1=str_in AND T2.COLUMN1=T1.COLUMN2 AND T3.COLUMN1=T2.COLUMN2 

UNION 

SELECT T4.COLUMN1, T4.COLUMN2 FROM TABLE1 AS T1, TABLE1 AS T2, TABLE1 AS T3, TABLE1 AS T4 WHERE T1.COLUMN1=str_in AND T2.COLUMN1=T1.COLUMN2 AND T3.COLUMN1=T2.COLUMN2 AND T4.COLUMN1=T3.COLUMN2;

OPEN C1;
RETURN;

END CRSUBJ/
```

Thanks :)

Comment: This looks like it's (possibly) for a recursive setup.  Are you navigating a tree structure?  Which version of DB2 are you on - most of the recent ones support recursive CTEs, which would give you multiple ways to control the depth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More specifically: In your example - you can't. What you effectively perform are four queries over TABLE1 and returning the resulting cursor back so it appears as ONE table to the caller. It would help to know more of the table structure and what you try to achieve to help you with your problem.

Comment: ok, I just managed to do it myself :3 Thanks anyway and next time I'll remember to mention more about table structure and the database.

Answer (score 0):

[Check documentation.](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.doc/admin/r0005649.htm)